efi stub warning
Before upgrading to 24.04 from 22.04, I would see dev/sda clean, xxxxx blocks, xxxxx files. Now, after a clean install and separate /home partition, I see efi stub failed to measure data from first event errorocode 0x800000009. I did notice my boot was not where I initially placed it, first in line, then /, then /home. Now, it is /, efi boot, /home.
The system boots, runs normally, no issues. Is this something to be concerned about?
Update 08/31/24   Rebuilt device, upgraded ram, now have separate SSD drive for boot/OS, apps, HDD for everything else. Was running 22.04, everything ran great, went with update to 24.04. Same efi error message pops up upon boot. Have noticed things are not as fast to load on 24.04 as they were on 22.04. Seems buggy, slow  and unstable.

Why would one concern about anything when the system runs normally without any issues?

@mook765 "EFI stub: WARNING: Failed to measure data for event 1:0x800000009" Maybe because it clearly says "Warning", which does clearly indicate there is an issue and is not normal. Either way, this seems to be an error related to BIOS settings or secure boot of some sort. I have a portable drive and get this error on some systems but not most.
